# How can I get rid of this weird barrier?

Tags: import, append, visibility

I appended the Utopia kit from Kitbash, and with it came this weird fog-like barrier. If I zoom out at all, I can no longer see the plane or any objects, even if I undo or hide everything. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it? It is EXTREMELY obstructive.[image]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your clipping end distance is set too low;

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did this only happen after I imported the kit? Did it somehow change my settings (I only imported the collection, not any settings as far as I know)?

Answer (score 0):

in 3D view, first select all, even if you cannot see them, and scale down to .01, then move objects toward you, using X, or Y axis,

also you may need to change you View Focal length. press the N key for the panel to display.

Trevor